# Password reset not saving to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, passwords, bcrypt

My code above runs without any errors but the new password isn't saved.

I've been following the bcrypt [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt), a [blog post](https://itnext.io/password-reset-emails-in-your-react-app-made-easy-with-nodemailer-bb27968310d7) and a video and think the three different sources have resulted in my missing something critical.
Any ideas why the new password isn't being saved?

```
module.exports.submitNewPassword = async (req, res) => {
    const slidedHeaderToken = req.headers.referer.slice(-40);
    const artist = await Artist.find({ resetPasswordToken: slidedHeaderToken, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } });
    if (!artist) {
        console.log("Artist doesn't exist");
    } else {
        const hashedPassword = async (pw) => {
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 12)
        }
        hashedPassword()
        artist.password = hashedPassword;
        resetPasswordToken = null;
        resetPasswordExpires = null;

        console.log("Successfully resubmitted password");
        res.redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you saving to the DB? What database API is this?

Comment: `artist.password = hashedPassword` using mongoose

Answer (score 0):

You should call `await artist.save()` function after you set some fields

Comment: Hi @zahid thanks for the response. I updated the code but am receiving error `TypeError: artist.save is not a function` ?

Comment: Can you try findOne instead of find in order to make sure that we should work on one instance only ?

Comment: Yes just tried and it comes back undefined (when I log) so the function kicks my error text `Artist doesn't exist` in the console.

Comment: Okey then make sure that the query filter matches at least one doc at your db

Comment: Hey Zahid you're spot on - this is the problem. `console.log(artist)` is coming back as an empty array. It's not null but if I change to `artist.find({ email: 'user@email.com' })` the query works. Something's off with my query by `slidedHeaderToken` although I just ran `console.log(slidedHeaderToken)` and it matches the database input. Very odd and I'm confused (have a similar comment on Barmar's response below)

Comment: It is interesting. I don't see the whole code from here but maybe you should check your database by using some tools like mongoDb Compass in order to see documents in detail visually

Answer (score 0):

When you make a change to the data using `FindOne`, you need to `save` it.

```
await yourVariable.save()
```

Comment: Updated the code but receive `TypeError: artist.save is not a function` ?

Answer (score 0):

`artists` is an array of all the artists matching the parameters in the call to `.find()`. If you just want to find one, use `.findOne()`.

Then after you modify it, use `.save()` to save it back to the database.

```
module.exports.submitNewPassword = async (req, res) => {
    const slidedHeaderToken = req.headers.referer.slice(-40);
    const artist = await Artist.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: slidedHeaderToken, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } });
    if (!artist) {
        console.log("Artist doesn't exist");
    } else {
        const hashedPassword = async (pw) => {
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 12)
        }
        hashedPassword()
        artist.password = hashedPassword;
        await artist.save();
        resetPasswordToken = null;
        resetPasswordExpires = null;
        console.log("Successfully resubmitted password");
        res.redirect('login');
    }
}
```

See the Mongoose tutorial [here](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/save#:%7E:text=Mongoose%27s%20save()%20function%20is,a%20good%20reason%20not%20to.).

Comment: Hi @barmar thanks for the response. This logs `Artist doesn't exist` in the console. findOne() isn't finding a document but find() does. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think `find()` is finding it? You're never testing whether there's anything in the array. An empty array is truthy in JavaScript.

Comment: What does `console.log(artist)` show in your original version?

Comment: Looks like you've figured out the problem... `console.log(artist)` is coming back as an empty array. It's not *null* but if I change to artist.find({ email: 'user@email.com' })` the query works. Something's off with my query by `slidedHeaderToken` although I just ran `console.log(slidedHeaderToken)` and it matches the database input. Very odd and I'm stumped

Comment: Obviously it doesn't really match, maybe there are differences in whitespace, capitalization, etc.

Comment: Okay - findOne *does* work I just have to comment out all the code starting with the if statement. Once the logic and password save rows are removed,`console.log(artist)` based on the findOne search gives me the correct document.